# How can I make animation with 1 camera and 2 nurbspath in blender?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

[image]

I have 1 camera and 2 nurbspath.
I wantto follow path 1 camera and 2 nurbspath. 
How can I do that ?

Comment: There is 1 way to do. Try create 2 cameras and use one camera for one NurbPath and other camera for another NurbPath. http://www.pasteall.org/blend/39176 here is demo file. To

Comment: To change animations switch another camera. You could try to mane one NurbsPath for one camera. You can't join after you make two separate NurbsPaths. For 2 Nurbspaths, create 2 cameras and switch them. As in picture http://www.pasteall.org/pic/95383

Comment: imho, you _can_ join 2 "path" objects, and make the object follow both, in the order. can you provide a file to create an example? eg, with http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: have two "follow path" and keyframe them ?